# What components would I need to receive SMS-CB messages?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, rf, cellphone

I could simply use a LTE modem for this (with a SIM Card). But since SMS-CB is an FTA (Free-To-Air) signal, having to buy a SIM card for this (I know, it's not expensive) would be overkill.

I am specifically looking to intercept EU-Alert/NL-Alert CB messages, for a little side project (using Arduino/uC).

What components could I use and where can I find some useful documentation to implement this into hardware and code (frequencies, data formats, etc)?

Comment: You still need to be connected to a cell service provider, so will need both a modem and a SIM. You don't need to pay for any messages. I use a SIM808 with an IOT SIM card with no money on it to receive time/location (cell tower and timezone) information with zero cost.

Comment: There are many M2M solutions that can be connected with a microcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd still want to use a 2G/LTE modem. That's it. You can certainly implement a GSM receiver as a software defined radio (there's *really* more than enough material on that), but it makes no sense in this context: you want to use a normal GSM functionality, so use normal GSM hardware.

And because you need to listen on the appropriate broadcast/cell organization channel in the case of GSM, or, much more complex technically, monitor the OFDM frames that each base station broadcasts to all subscribers in their cell¹, you'd really want to lock on to that base station.

That's basically all that a modem does in the absence of data to communicate.
So, get a modem. I'm not sure you need an active subscriber identity to make modems listen purely and receive cell broadcasts; in GSM, you could send SMSCB on the *basic* or *extended* cell broadcast channels; you should be able to read the *basic* channel without being registered, but whether or not your specific modem does that wihtout a SIM is a different question.

In 3G, the cell broadcast service is called [Service Area Broadcast](https://osmocom.org/projects/cellular-infrastructure/wiki/Service_Area_Broadcast), and due to the significantly more complex air interface, you'll really want a modem that has locked onto the basestation.

Since this is probably in context of German emergency systems, 3G won't help you much, but 2G is going to be around for a while; so I'd guess a pure GSM modem might be the way to go.

---

¹ intentionally not using the technically correct abbreviations here, because, man there are many